# What should we do with the tag [experts]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

## TL;DR:

[experts](/questions/tagged/experts) has <s>25</s> 14 questions but hasn't tag wiki. The [Frequent tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experts?tab=Frequent) shows <s>9</s> 4 questions. All the Top Askers have 1 question each. The Top Answerer is [Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/98786/robert-cartaino) with 2 answers and a score of <s>34</s> 35.

The hot answers are two

- [PolyGeo's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315545/289691) to [Harder question, when missing an expert are far less treated, even if they are "good" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315541/289691)
- [Piro's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334446/289691) to [Ways to make impact on a site in which you have little knowledge of the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140988/289691)

There is also [experience](/questions/tagged/experience) but this one only has 9 questions.
[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/289691) has "SME" that are the initials of *subject matter expert*.

What should we do with [experts](/questions/tagged/experts)?

---

I have reviewed most of the questions having [experts](/questions/tagged/experts), many of the them apparently used this tag becasued the post included the word *expert*, most of them to mean "user able to answer a question", not because the question asked something about the meaning or this word or the role of *experts* compared to *non-experts* as it's done in other questions. I retagged several of those questions.

---

From a long time I have being asking my self about community health. Searching about the users that better understand the site scope and workings, I found the tag [experts](/questions/tagged/experts), but this tag hasn't a tag wiki.

It has only <s>25</s> 14 questions.

I have found posts and comments discussing about

- publicly recognized experts
- industry experts
- niche experts
- gold badge tag holders
- high reputation users
- users suffering the [Dunning-Krugger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)
- users suffering the [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)

So I'm wondering if [experts](/questions/tagged/experts) should be used in questions about

- all of the above
- none none of the above

Possible related tags:

- [experience](/questions/tagged/experience) has 8 questions
  No tag wiki.
- [location](/questions/tagged/location) has 62 questions

  > For questions about the Location field in the user profile, careers/jobs and/or in the User table (SEDE)
- [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) has 920 questions

  > New users are those users who may be new to the Stack Exchange Q&A format, and generally have a low reputation score, which starts from 1 at the time of registration.
- [question-quality](/questions/tagged/question-quality) has 168 questions

  > is for questions that address the quality of questions and how it should affect their treatment.
- [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation) has 4,494 questions

  > Measurement of a user's contributions to the site, and the extent to which the community "trusts" that user with extra privileges.
- [spoonfeeding](/questions/tagged/spoonfeeding) has 4 questions

  > Spoonfeeding is the meta meme name for giving the answers to questions asked by users who haven't done any noticeable research.
- [users](/questions/tagged/users) has 594 questions

  > This tags is for general questions about users and user accounts.

---

- [academic](/questions/tagged/academic)

  > For questions about the usage of Stack Exchange in the academic world. (For questions about Academia Stack Exchange specifically, please use Academia's own Meta site instead.)
- [research](/questions/tagged/research)

  > A tag for questions involving studies of the Stack Exchange data or community.

---

### Site Proposals (pre- and Area 51)

- [site-proposal](/questions/tagged/site-proposal) has 2,181 questions

  > A placeholder for old site proposal discussions. If you have an idea for a new Stack Exchange site, you should propose it on Area 51.
- [definition-phase](/questions/tagged/definition-phase) has 601 questions

  > The start of a new site. This is the first phase of a new site, where only question titles are proposed and then voted on in order to define the meaning of the new site.
- [commitment-phase](/questions/tagged/commitment-phase) has 114 questions

  > For questions about the Commitment phase on Area 51 proposals.
- [site-promotion](/questions/tagged/site-promotion) has 57 questions

  > Questions about attracting new users to a Stack Exchange site or to Area51 site proposal
  > Anyway, rather than discuss in this post what is an expert, the question is What should we do with [experts](/questions/tagged/experts)?
- [site-evaluation](/questions/tagged/site-evaluation) has 23 questions

  > Community self-evaluations was an answer quality evaluation process that took place on some Stack Exchange sites from 2012 to 2015.

### Obsolete tags

- [jobs](/questions/tagged/jobs) has 2,171 questions. Questions with this tag are obsolete as Stack Overflow Jobs was retired.

  > For questions on the new Stack Overflow Jobs in the context of all sites in the network. For questions specific to the current implementation of Stack Overflow Jobs, please ask your question on Meta Stack Overflow.

---

## Related

Some results from [[discussion] what is expert](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiscussion%5D%20what%20is%20expert)

### Role Playing Games Meta

- [Should a question be judged on its level of "expertise"?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/782/81006)

### English Language and Usage Meta

- [What is "chat with an expert"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3869/355513)

### English Language Learners Meta

- [What is our expert self-serving, self-sustaining audience?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/172)

### Drupal Answers Meta

- [What is with the 'Chat with an Expert' popup I just started seeing on DA?](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2408)

### Genealogy & Family History Meta

- https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1455/15558

### Economics Meta

- [Is this site only for "expert-level questions"?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30)
- [How do you ask "expert level questions"?](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/128)

### Meta Stack Exchange

- [What is required to make a stackexchange web site successful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4245/289691)
- [The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387356/289691)

Comment: We need some experts to answer this.

Comment: Please nominate experts to answer this! / Perpect oportunity to use the share link :D

Comment: I can see a potential benefit in having a tag to group all the questions about "Are SE sites for experts?" and the like together... But I'm not sure.

Comment: @V2Blast I did a search in SE and found several question like that across metas.

Comment: @V2Blast As the tag can't be used to tag questions across sites, I think that [tag:excerpts] should be *burninated*. Posted an answer, without suggesting the burnination explicitly yet. What do you think?

Comment: I just noticed the typo in the above link, sorry. The correct link is [tag:experts]

Answer (score 1):

[experts](/questions/tagged/experts) was used as a meta-tag.

From [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/289691)

> **Don't use meta tags.** Even if it already exists. A meta tag is any tag that doesn't categorize the content of the question, but simply indicates the nature of the question. Examples include `homework` or `hard-question`.

There are some posts that are using the term *expert* to make reference to the corresponding general knowledge concept, something like *someone that has a deep understanding of a topic and / or whom opinion is considered important regarding topics that are difficult*.

Wikipedia has article [Expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert) because its purpose is to be a repository of general knowledge.

Also it has an article about [Stack Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange) but the use of the term *expert* is marginal. By the other hand this article has a section of **notable users** including one Nobel prize winner, several Fields Medal winners, the Founders and other scientiests and mathematicians.

With exception of the mandatory tags and the status tags, on this site tags should not be meta-tags and should not be used for general knowledge concepts.

Instead of [experts](/questions/tagged/experts) use

- [users](/questions/tagged/users)
- [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users)
- [top-users](/questions/tagged/top-users)
- [moderators](/questions/tagged/moderators)

If a question is about making a site or question interesting for Nobel prize winners, Fields Medal winners, the Founders, scientiests and mathematicians I think that we should not use [experts](/questions/tagged/experts). If it's really necessary to have a tag for posts about this people we might use something like

- notable-people
- top-notch

Anyway, that might be discussed in another question, when the the real need arises.

Reference

- [When should I create a new tag? How do I request a new tag if I don't have enough rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146949/289691)